# jQuery loop pausing in a particular spot

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange issue with a script that I've created. My jQuery/Javascript skills aren't great (I'm still learning) and am hoping someone could help me understand why this is happening.

I'm developing an online store and have a strip of 4 divs floated next to each other across the top with notices I'd like to highlight for my customers.

The site is responsive, so for mobile I wanted to reduce this to one notice at a time, and fade out and fade in each notice.

I also didn't want to simply use CSS media queries to show and hide a desktop and mobile version as I feel that might work against me, SEO-wise, if I was to repeat the content twice. Therefore I've put together a jQuery script to grab the content of the first set of divs, put them into an array, and fade in and out each notice in a loop.

I thought I'd done it however noticed something strange in both Firefox and Chrome: it loops through once fine, but then stops completely when displaying "100% happiness guarantee" the second time, and I'm at a loss as to why.

I've created a JSFiddle with the code I'm using here:
http://jsfiddle.net/qewwmnge/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Transform the highlights div into a 1 line bar for mobile devices

    // Read the highlights div content into an array
    var highlights = new Array();
    $("#highlights").find("div").each(function(){
        highlights.push($(this).html());
    });

    $text = $('#highlights-mobile div'),
    delay = 5;

    // Set the initial highlight item on page load
    $text.html( highlights[0] );

    // Loop through the array and fade in each highlight
    function loop ( delay ) {
        $.each( highlights, function ( i, elm ){
            if ($text.html() != highlights[i]) { // Skip the first fade in on the first loop so it doesn't repeat itself
                $text.delay( delay*1E3).fadeOut();
                $text.queue(function(){
                    $text.html( highlights[i] );
                    $text.dequeue();
                });
                $text.fadeIn();
                $text.queue(function(){
                    if ( i == highlights.length -1 ) {
                        loop(delay);   
                    }
                    $text.dequeue();
                });
            }
        });
    }
    loop( delay );

});
```

If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: i ha v commented some unwanted queue function .. now its working ..check out   http://jsfiddle.net/qewwmnge/1/

Comment: There is also one issue that after first cycle get complete, first div  never comes into loop to fadeIn. so I updated http://jsfiddle.net/qewwmnge/2/

Comment: Some advise concerning JS: instead of `new Array()` better style is using an array literal `var highlights = [];`, also the `$text` and `delay` variables are not declared properly - you are missing a `var` there - so they will become accidental globals. You might want to consider using something like [jshint](http://jshint.com/install/) that catches such issues. A good read on JS is [Douglas Crockford on JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/). Happy Scripting!

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'll be sure to check out both of those as well, @vanhelgen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery code contain queue/dequeue logic, there is no need to do that.

It's better to use simple jquery for same thing. See this demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vce2da3s/)

```js
$(function () {
    var $highlights = $("#highlights-mobile div");
    var divsHTML = new Array();
 $("#highlights").find("div").each(function(){
  divsHTML.push($(this).html());
 });
    
    var position = -1;
    
    !function loop() {
        position = (position + 1) % divsHTML.length;
        $highlights.html(divsHTML[position])
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .delay(1000)
        .fadeOut(1000,loop);
    }();
});
```

```css
#highlights, #highlights-mobile {
 background-color: #E8E8E8;
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 overflow: auto;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#highlights h4, #highlights-mobile h4 {
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}

#highlights-mobile {
 padding: 10px;
}

#highlights-mobile a, #highlights a {
 color: #444;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#highlights div {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 border-right: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
 color: #444;
 overflow: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 }



@media (min-width: 768px) {
 #highlights {
  display: block;
 }

 

 #highlights div:last-child {
 border-right: none;
 }
}



@media (min-width: 768px) {
 #highlights div {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 border-right: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
 color: #444;
 overflow: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 }

 #highlights div:last-child {
 border-right: none;
 }

 #highlights h4 {
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 }

 #highlights a {
 color: #444;
 text-decoration: none;
 }

 #highlights-mobile {
  display: none;
 }
}



@media (max-width: 767px) {

 #highlights {
  display: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="highlights-mobile">
 <div style="display: block;">
 </div>
</div>

<div id="highlights">
 <div>
  <a href="/refurbishment-process"><h4>Professionally refurbished</h4>Old school gear, good as new</a>
 </div>
 <div>
  <h4>Free shipping</h4>On orders over $250, nation wide
 </div>
 <div>
  <a href="/happiness-guarantee"><h4>100% happiness guarantee</h4>Easy returns and a 60 day warranty</a>
 </div>
 <div>
  <a href="/bitcoin"><h4>5% off your order</h4>When you pay with Bitcoin</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that's much cleaner than my crude attempt! Much appreciated!